# How do writers not block reads in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, transaction, snapshot-isolation, acid, mvcc

Since readers do not block writers and writers do not block readers is what MVCC is all about, how does postgresql prevent writers who are in the process of committing their changes to blocks/pages prevent a reader from reading this inconsistent data?

So from what I understand about PostgreSQL's MVCC, each table is represented as a heap file and each heap file contains a collection of pages / blocks which are 8 kb segments of information.

So say two transaction `T1` and `T2` concurrently running and `T1` decides to make some modification to `block1`. So at first, `T1` reads `block1` and makes modifications to it in-memory and when it's finally done, it decides to commit; ie actually write back these in-memory changes to `block1`. So I understand that `xmax` of the previous entries it modified are set to `id(T1)` and a new entry is created with `xmin` set to `id(T1)`. Now what I find difficult is, say while the actual commit process occurs for `T1`, say `T2` reads (while the write by `T1` has started but not ended). How is this case handled?

Any answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the whole idea of MVCC - **Multi-Version**-Concurrency-Control.

Whenever data is being modified while there are other active transactions reading it, or have read it previously (depending on the reader transaction's isolation level), a copy of the pre-modified data is set aside for these transactions so as not to block them. This copy is kept until all those reader transactions complete, so they can see a consistent version.

This is the price that you pay with MVCC as the server needs to maintain multiple copies of the same data, vs. lock based (pessimistic) isolation that uses only one copy of the data, but introduces potential blocking. No free meals :-)

You can read all the details about it here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/mvcc.html

I also invite you to take my [pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/postgresql-data-manipulation-playbook/table-of-contents) on this exact topic which discusses MVCC and isolation levels in depth, with real life examples.
Individuals can get a [1 month pluralsight free trial](https://help.pluralsight.com/help/individual-free-trial).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized that I haven't been specific enough while asking the question and have added some additional clarification. Would be really helpful if you could clarify now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If t1 hasn't committed yet, t2 will get his own copy of the original data. T1 may err and rollback as well. There is probably some very short "lock" to protect memory spaces while t1's copy becomes the "current" state but it's true for all memory operations, even reading from disk or flushing to disk. Do you have a specific concern? The documentation is pretty verbose but it's an implementation detail I wouldn't worry about. Your consistency and isolation guarantees are logical. Implementation may change in the next version...

Comment: Thank you for getting back. And upon further investigation, I came across Read-Copy-Update mechanism and yes I assumed that MVCC somehow got away without using a lock while making t1's copy the current state. It would be really great if you could shed some light on how t1's copy becomes the "current" state. It need not be specific to postgresql. A general explanation on how one would go about this would be very helpful

Comment: If you after the internals of MVCC implementations, I recommend that you buy or rent this article. https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=356842.356846. It is far too complicated for this forum, and I honestly don't remember all the bits and bytes of each implementation. Sorry... This also seems like an interesting resource that you might find useful [TLDR] - https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/mvcc.pdf

Comment: _a copy of the pre-modified data is set aside for these transactions so as not to block them_: There's no such copy done with PostgreSQL, at least not in released versions. This step applies to other databases such as Oracle with its undo records.

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks for your comment. I will check the documentation again later, and correct my answer if needed.

Answer (score 4):

> Now what I find difficult is, say while the actual commit process
>   occurs for T1, say T2 reads (while the write by T1 has started but not
>   ended). How is this case handled?

It doesn't have to be handled because this step doesn't really exist.

You're making the assumption that transactions modify blocks exclusively in memory, until there is a commit, at which point all modified blocks would be flushed to disk. 
But it doesn't work like that at all. If it did, the amount of changes that a transaction could do would be limited by the memory, and that's not the case.

Also, MVCC in Postgres works at the row level, not at the page level.

A logical row in a table is materialized on disk as multiple versions of that row, versioned with the [`(xmin,xmax)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) pseudo-columns. When updating a row, instead of overwriting the "current" content on disk, a transaction creates a new version with the new content. Each transaction knows what version (if any) of the row is visible to itself based on these per-row `(xmin,xmax)` values. When a row has a version that is no longer visible by any transaction, vacuum will eventually notice it and reclaim its space on disk. These are called "dead rows".

So there is never a "flush" step during which a transaction T2 would need to read a row changed and committed by T1 and would be uncertain about whether it's reading a pre-T1 or post-T1 value. The reads made by T2 will always reach the only version of the row that T2 can see, thanks to the filtering with `(xmin,xmax)`.

The visibility switch to the new version of rows that have been created by T1 is **instantaneous** from the point of view of T2: it corresponds to a switch of snapshot, which may happen during T2 if it runs under the *Read Committed* isolation level.